# How to login with a scrapy spider when the login page is as GET method instead of a POST method?

Tags: web-scraping, authentication, request, scrapy

I plan to login this [website](https://www.paris-turf.com/) with a scrapy spider.
The login page is a GET request method

[image]

As you can see, this is a GET method and there is not any attributes shown for the id and passeword.

[image]
but in the HTML code, there is a link(it does not work when a write it in the url bar of my browser), it indicates a POST method `method="post"`. But when I login, there is no POST file appearing in the networks of the browser console.

What to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a POST request in the network log, but you have to enable "Persist Logs" ("Conserver les journaux"):
[image]
This POST request issues a redirect which causes the log to clear without that setting.

One thing to keep in mind here is that you need to grab the CSRF token. Here is a quick example for how you can login using scrapy shell:

`scrapy shell https://www.paris-turf.com/`

Then run the following:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest

# GET the login form fragment.
fetch('https://www.paris-turf.com/compte/login')

# Grab the CSRF token.
token = response.css('[name="_csrf_token"]::attr(value)').get()

# Login. This issues a redirect.
fetch(FormRequest('https://www.paris-turf.com/compte/login_check', formdata={'_username': 'your@email.com', '_password': 'yourpassword', '_csrf_token': token}))

# Get the logged in username.
response.css('.media-heading .text-italic::text').get()
```

Comment: I cannot understand why, I updated Firefox few minutes ago, it still indicates GET, even if I checked Persist logs. That is mysterious.

Comment: Your code works. It redirect to my account page. I gonna learn how to implement it in my spider. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is POST and the post variables `_username` and `_password` are being sent:
(screen cap from Firefox when I clicked "Edit and resend" in the right had side panel)

[image: Screencap of Network tools during login]

Comment: That is because I checked only HTML, and the POST is a JSON type.